# Conenct many list to one list

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

I must do in Sharepoint 2010 one list from 5-6 lists, and update this main conected list in the night. How Could I do this? Can I do this by Sharepoint Designer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what your after is a linked data source view in sharepoint designer!

its relativly easy:

for a walk-through guide follow:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194252/How-to-Link-Two-Lists-and-Create-a-Combined-Ciew-i

for msdn

SPD 2007

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-sources-in-a-single-data-view-HA010099144.aspx

SPD 2010

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/create-data-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-HA101631630.aspx

there are other ways todo it but as you noted SPD..

**EDIT**

yes you can:

> You can modify a Data View by using SharePoint Designer 2010. A Data
>   View provides read and write access to a wide variety of sources,
>   including database queries, XML documents, Web services, SharePoint
>   lists and libraries, and server-side scripts. You can also create a
>   Data View that displays data from multiple data sources.
>
> After you insert a Data View into your page, you can also use the
>   WYSIWYG tools in SharePoint Designer 2010 to add or remove columns,
>   filter, sort, and group fields, and change font formatting and overall
>   layout. When you format the Data View using these WYSIWYG tools,
>   SharePoint Designer 2010 inserts the necessary Extensible Stylesheet
>   Language (XSL) directly into the page so you don’t have to know how to
>   write XSL. Of course, if you want to write the XSL directly, you can
>   always open the page in Code view.
>
> Note    If you’re primarily working with lists and libraries as data
>   sources, you can use Data Views or List Views to read and write data
>   to those data sources. List Views are similar to Data Views, but they
>   include the added benefit of full support for view customization in
>   the browser. Learn more about List Views in the See Also section.

taken from:

SPD 2010

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/create-data-views-in-sharepoint-designer-HA101631628.aspx

SPD 2007

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/edit-delete-or-insert-records-in-a-data-view-HA010119113.aspx

**EDIT 2**

as noted within the link its returning xaml but you need to format the look and feel ;)

to get you started on that you need to follow this to display the info you want or the look and feel, more specificly tho for you scroll down to **Apply view styles** as that is what your talking about, it will change it from a text list to somthing nicer ;).

> When you create a list or Data View, by default the data is typically
>   displayed in a basic table layout. You can change the layout of the
>   view quickly and easily by applying a different view style. For
>   example, you can change the basic table layout of your view to one
>   that presents the view with borders, columns, or bulleted lists.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/customize-data-views-and-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-HA101631678.aspx

Comment: Using SPD linked data source, if I do the above requirement, will I be able to edit/update the values in main connected list/view.?

Comment: just updated my answer, its yes.

Comment: Thanks for replay, But if I done this I getting a playn text, not a list. How can I add Data Source to the List

Comment: just updated answer